# Conditionally create json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, apisauce

I'm using APISauce to create a post request to my server.

This works fine, and `id, title and desc` are variables that I pass in a function.
return client.post("/workout", {
userId: id,
title: title,
description: desc,
});

description is optional, and I can't post it if the value is empty.

I can do it this way -

```
if (desc){
return client.post("/workout", {
        userId: id,
        title: title,
        description: desc,
    });
}else
return client.post("/workout", {
        userId: id,
        title: title,
        
});
```

But this is a lot of duplicate, so I just want to check if there is a more efficient way of doing this? Can I check the description field within the JSON object?

Comment: If whatever you're using doesn't automagically filter out undefined values, just create the base object, add the description if present, and have a single `post` call using the created object. There's duplication here only because you haven't separated the parameter creation from the post.

Comment: I can do that way actually yeah, but it'd be a repetition nonetheless, where I'd be recreating an object, one with description and the other without.

Comment: No, you'd create an object, and conditionally add a property to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
client.post("/workout", {
    userId: id,
    title: title,
    description: desc,
});
```

there's no need for the check. If `desc` is undefined the key `description` will be removed when stringified to JSON.

Comment: I just tried this and I still got undefined

 const description = desc ? desc : undefined;
 console.log("Post workout " + description);
 return client.post("/workout", {
  userId: id,
  title: title,
  description: description,
 });
Even though description is undefined, I'm still getting an error because description shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Following up with what Dave Newton suggested in the comments, it would work like the below

```js
const body = {
  userId: id,
  title
};
if (desc) {
  body.description = desc;
}
client.post('/workout', body);
```

You're only creating the object once and if the property exists, you're setting it on the object.